# Partial inheritance between constructors in different files (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

I have two constructors in two different js files. I want the constructors to have two methods that are the same (same name and functionality) and one method that is called the same but works differently (same name but not the same functionality). There will also be a couple of other properties that are the same in both constructors.

The way I have tried to achieve this is by having one of the constructors inherit the other and then declare a new method with the same name as an old one (see below). This works well enough (I believe) when the constructors are in the same file, but when they are in separate files I seem to lose the connection. The inheritance doesn't work.

The code looks similar to this:

File 1: (someone suggested removing the first line to avoid circulation, but it didn't seem to make any difference)

```
var Child = require("./Child");

var Parent = function(name, age) {
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
};

Parent.prototype.calculate1 = function(a, b) {
   return a + b;
};

Parent.prototype.calculate1 = function(a, b) {
   return a - b;
};

Parent.prototype.calculate3 = function() {
   return "Armageddon";
};

module.exports = Parent;
```

File 2:

```
var Parent = require("./Parent");

var Child = function(name, age) {
   Parent.call(this, name, age);
};

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

Child.prototype.calculate3 = function() {
   return "Deep Impact";
};

module.exports = Child;
```

So, I guess it's more like two questions. 1) Is this a good way to solve my problem? And 2) why doesn't it work when the constructors are in separate files? In Webstorm I get a notice that the method call (in Parent.call) is an unresolved function or method call.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using such a complex class inheritance? Even in ES6, classes are a hack in JS...JS is more about functional programming.

Comment: Well, I didn't know it was that complex =) It just so happens I have two constructors that are identical apart from this one method. At one point in the program, there will be objects from both constructors in an array and I will call the method for (and expect different results from) each object.

Comment: JS supports functional programming and object oriented programming paradigms, and this type of inheritance isn't that complex once you're used to it. That being said, I don't use this style. IMO, it's more attractive for people who come from OOP backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple problems with your example here.

1. You have circular dependencies between your two files, as in they both rely on each other. In general, that's a bad idea. Files should not BOTH depend on each other as that is a recipe for unexpected behavior.
2. You need to use a 3rd constructor to solve your problem called `Person` or something. Both `Parent` and `Child` should inherit from `Person`, and you should define the common methods in `Person`, and the ones where they differ on the individual files.

Here's an example of how it should probably work:

```
// Person.js
function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.someShareMethod = function (a, b) {
  return a + b;
};

module.exports = Person;

// Parent.js
var Person = require('./Person');

function Parent (name, age) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
}

Parent.prototype = Object.create(Person.protoype);

Parent.prototype.someSelfMethod = function (a, b) {
  return a * b;
};

module.exports = Parent;

// Child.js
var Person = require('./Person');

function Child (name, age) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Person.protoype);

Child.prototype.someSelfMethod = function (a, b) {
  return a - b;
};

module.exports = Child;
```

All that being said, the general concept of your inheritance should work. Once constructor can inherit from another, and that is a perfectly good practice. I broke out your code (with circular reference removed), ran this locally, and got the expected output:

```
var Parent = require('./Parent'),
    Child = require('./Child');

var p = new Parent('Bob', 40);

console.log(p.calculate3());

var c = new Child('Stan', 12);

console.log(c.calculate3());
```

Which logged this:

```
Armageddon
Deep Impact
```

If you didn't get that, I think the problem is how you've used your classes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! About your second point, that's a typo in my post and not something that is actually in the code. Sorry about that. I thought I had gone over the post enough times but apparently not. About your third point, doesn't that seem like a lot of work just to have one constructor inherit from another? I mean, one of the reasons I want to use inheritance is to avoid writing too much code.

Comment: But if I understand you correctly then my solution, to have one constructor inherit the other and then change some of the content, either doesn't work or isn't recommended.

Comment: @Candleout I updated the response to address your comment. The code works from me, so if it's not working for you, I think it's a usage issue and your should try my example.