# how can I inherit a js class from another js class which are separate files?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a basic Shape function in a separated js file then I have another js file for Circle object and a third js file for Square object. How can I inherit the Shape object to the prototype of Circle and Square? I am trying to mimic what I always do on C# where I separate an abstract class and inherit it to other classes.

Comment: Load the `Shape` file first ? Btw, is it pure javascript?

Comment: yup it is pure javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take advantage of [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

```
// Shape.js
export default class Shape {
    constructor() {
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then in a separate file:

```
// Circle.js
import Shape from "./Shape.js"

export default class Circle extends Shape {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    // ...
}
```

The real annoyance is that the `import` reference is always relative to the current file. If you're using Webpack to transpile and/or bundle your module, you can take advantage of their [resolve option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is `require`. Like this:

`var Parent = require("./Parent");`

Then you can use `Parent`'s functions like an OO language would offer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601909/partial-inheritance-between-constructors-in-different-files-javascript) for a full example.

EDIT: The other answers about exporting and importing are much better if you're looking to more closely replicate OO. Would recommend those over `require`.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) freely.

**Shape.js**

```
export class Shape {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "hello, world";
    }
}
```

**Circle.js**

```
import {Shape} from "./Shape.js";

export class Circle extends Shape {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.bar = "goodbye, world";
    }
}
```